# Ms Access save as image JPG

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to save a report as an image (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG) in Microsoft Access using this code instead of saving it as .SNP)?

```
Private Sub Command150_Click()
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Playa1", acFormatSNP, 
"C:\Users\Tony\Documents\Testo\pretty.snp"
End Sub
```

I'd like to save it as pretty.jpg

Comment: No. Those are not available formats https://access-excel.tips/access-vba-docmd-outputto-method/. Would have to convert with another software. Review https://www.print-driver.com/how-to/convert-access-to-jpeg

Comment: Reasons for this? As a report usually contains text, a PDF should be prefered (smaller, indexable). To convert PDF's to JPEG or TIFF I prefer [Irfan View](https://www.irfanview.net/) as it has nice command-line options (enables me to show PDF's on reports, by converting them to JPEG's in background).