# Access Form Snapshot in Body of Email

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to grab an image of a form on submission in order to insert it in the body of an email. I've tried a couple different solutions, but some haven't worked, and some haven't been exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm using MS Access 2016 on Windows 10, so Application.Sendkeys will not work to take a screenshot.

The first thing I tried was:

```
DoCmd.SendObject acOutputForm, "form_name", etc..
```

However, this just attaches the pdf to the email, where I'm really tring to get it inserted in the body.
Next I tried exporting a pdf, then uploading it and embedding it in the body, only to find that this isn't possible through SMTP.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "fNewReqPLT", _
    acFormatPDF, "file_path", _
    True, "", 0, acExportQualityScreen

myAttachments.Add "file_path"
```

```
With OutlookMail
        .To = "email@email.com"
        .Subject = "Approval Request"
        .HTMLBody = "<object data=""file_path""height=1250 width=781></object>"
        .Display
    End With
```

However, it doesn't show in the body of the email when I try to pull a PDF file that was already on my desktop, and when I try to pull the file that I am currently exporting, it doesn't even make it to the outlook part where it adds the attachments and displays the message. The sub ends before this. I'm assuming it's because the pdf is opening after saving.

I guess I have two questions:

1. Can I export a PDF with a similar screenshot of the form without having it open afterwards?
2. Can I convert that snapshot of the form to a JPEG or PNG so I can easily embed it in .HTMLBody?

Any other suggestions on how to get the image added to the body are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: You already determined can't do 'screenshot', can DoCmd.OutputTo to PDF. Then converting to another format is a challenge - review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435188/ms-access-save-as-image-jpg. Use HTML <img> tag to imbed image in email.